# Como pegar informações de uma function e distribuí-las numa view?

Tags: php, htaccess, funções

Eu fiz uma função que recebe dados do banco de dados conforme parametros passados por `$_GET[]` ... Como posso usar estas informações em outra parte do meu sistema?

```
function db_tratcontent(){

    $slug = friendly_url(($_GET['slug_trat']));
    $tipo = 'tratamentos';

    global $pdo;

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tb_paginas WHERE tipo = '$tipo' AND url_amigavel = '$slug'";
    $exc = $pdo->query($sql);
    $cnt = $exc->rowCount();
    $hpg = url_site().'home';

    if($cnt == 1){ $dados = $exc->fetch(); } else { exit(header("Location: $hpg")); }

}
```

Se eu colocar o código abaixo para tentar resgatar o que está dentro de ***$dados*** fora da função, não funciona:

```
echo $dados['titulo'];
```

Estou tentando preencher a view ***tratamentos.php*** com os dados retornados dessa função sem sucesso. Como estou aprendendo, ainda não sei como funciona. Uma forma não elegante de fazer isso é colocar todo o html dentro da view mas acho que isso é desnecessário ou é assim que funciona mesmo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apenas retorne com o `return`

Essa linha

```
if($cnt == 1){ $dados = $exc->fetch(); } else { exit(header("Location: $hpg")); }
```

troque-a por isso

```
if ($cnt == 1)
    return $exc->fetch();
else
    exit(header("Location: $hpg"));
```

PAra receber o resultado da função

```
$dados = db_tratcontent();
```

Então poderá fazer:

```
echo $dados['titulo'];
```

**Observação:**

Há muitos erros conceituais e também de lógica. Mas prefiro não comentar para evitar complicar uma resposta tão simples.

**UPDATE**

**Isset()**

Nesse trecho  `$slug = friendly_url(($_GET['slug_trat']));`, verifique antes se o índice `slug_trat` existe e valide-o com filtros e as validações que necessitar para o dado que espera receber.

No exemplo abaixo vou mostrar somente um filtro com trim(), o qual remove espaços no começo e no fim, caso existam. Mas vc deve validar conforme o seu modelo de negócio. Se for receber número, filtre e valide como número, se for email, filtre e valide como email, etc.

Esse trecho `$slug = friendly_url(($_GET['slug_trat']));`, pode trocar por algo como isso:

```
$slug_trat = null;

if (isset($_GET['slug_trat']))
   $slug_trat = trim($_GET['slug_trat']);

if (empty($_GET['slug_trat']))
   retun null;

$slug = friendly_url($slug_trat);
```

Note que está usando parênteses desnecessários `(($_GET['slug_trat']))`. No exemplo acima, removi o excesso.

Ainda assim há erros conceituais mesmo nesse script de correção que estou recomendando. Apenas procurei ser mais simples possível. Mas para explicar conceitos, design pattern, etc, é muito complexo e realmente não é viável explicar nesse post.

**Global**

Outro ponto que não é errado, mas é recomendado evitar usar, é o recurso "global".

Isso também envolve questões conceituais, mas vou explicar brevemente o uso técnico.

O uso de global, torna um objeto acessível de qualquer lugar que seja invocado, exceto, em casos específicos de funções anônimas com callback onde precisa invocar por referência para ter "acesso global".

Ficou confuso com esse último parágrafo? rsrs

Isso é só o começo mas, resumindo, o uso do global faz com que perca-se o controle de acessibilidade de um objeto. Tal objeto pode ser usado em qualquer lugar indiscriminadamente, tornando o código difícil de depurar quando for necessário um debug ou outras situações diversas.

Vale lembrar que global nada tem a ver com as variáveis de escopo global pre definidas pelo PHP como $_SERVER, $_GET, $_POST, dentre outros.

Aí também é outra conversa, tão complexa quanto o que discutimos aqui.

**header location**

O uso de redirecionamento dentro da função é algo bem grotesco.

Procure entender sobre como organizar o código em camadas, onde cada camada tem sua responsabilidade bem definida. O modelo básico é o chamado MVC. Pesquise sobre MVC.

**Padrões de código**

A nomenclatura é importante e o estilo a ser usado depende do padrão de código que deseja aplicar.

Basicamente, evite funções com nomes estranhos como "db_tratcontent". Os nomes devem ser intuitivos e o mais curto possível.

Como exemplo, db_tratcontent, podemos entender que db é database. Mas o que seria tratcontent? Tratamento de conteúdo?

Mesmo assim parece sem sentido e também mistura dois idiomas.

Mantenha um padrão com um idioma internacionalizado, no caso, é o inglês.

Para escrever códigos melhores, pesquise por padrões de código.

Comece pelo órgão PHP-FIG, http://www.php-fig.org/

Comment: Gostaria de saber sobre estes erros para incrementar meu aprendizado e conhecimento permitindo assim evoluir no aprendizado mesmo que fosse só no comentário ... Agradecido.

Comment: adicionei na resposta. Postei de um jeito bem informal e rápido, pois não disponho de tempo. Espero que seja útil.